# Programming language candidate for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

Can anyone suggest which is a potentially best candidate for the above? Python or?

Thank you.

Best regards,

Comment: Python is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go for python it's super easy to learn and all. But I would suggest that focus more on the statistics and math behind it because the implementation is quite easy. For alternatives, you can use C++